# how install grafana with helm and with a path "/grafana" instead of path "/"

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-helm

I've define a Ingress rule on path /grafana
I understand that I need also to configure root_url
I'm looking for the correct way to pass the root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/ with a command line like :

```
helm install --namespace grafana -n grafana stable/grafana --set rbac.pspEnabled=false  --set grafana.ini="{root_path = https://ingress-ops.nd-int-ops-paas.itn/grafana/ }"
```

I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

`--set 'grafana\.ini'.server.root_url=https://ingress-ops.nd-int-ops-paas.itn/grafana`

works fine